# Send download link to remote computer and initiate a download on that computer

Tags: windows, chrome, download-manager

I'm looking for software that would allow me to send a link for a download to a remote computer. This file would then be downloaded on that computer.

I have similar software for µTorrent and SABnzbd that allows me to right-click on a torrent or nzb link and choose an option to send that link to a remote computer for processing by µTorrent or SABnzbd.

There is another thread here that recommends using JDownloader, but I was hoping for something simpler. I don't seem to be able to send just the one link for the file. It processes all the links on the webpage and then requires user input to download the correct file.

Is there a download manager that has this functionality or can anyone suggest ways to accomplish this? I'm at a loss. The target machine that handles the downloads is running Windows 10. The other machines would be either Windows or OS X. The browser is Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't find a tool, then I would recommend remoting in to the other PC using TeamViewer or TightVNC.

Comment: You can't force a computer to download a file. That's a security risk. How will you be sending the link? By email? Why not DropBox or Google Drive? Then send a link to the file and let the person download it, or if they are subscribed to the folder, it will be downloaded to their DropBox automatically. If you want full control, install Cygwin and sshd, then have the owner give you an account, and you can use scp to copy a file to their computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; TeamViewer is what I currently use but it's a pain to open a remote desktop each time.

Comment: Forcing another computer to download a file (or perform a similar action)  can be done.  As I indicated,  there are tools designed for µTorrent, SABnzbd, Deluge, etc.  that send the file link to the target computer and have the appropriate program download the file. JDownloader will accomplish what I want, but at an overkill level.  No security risk, it's my computer.  SSH is unnecessary.  I can map a drive and drop the file.  I just want to offload the download to my other computer by right clicking the link and sending it to my desktop to download. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @BostonScott You are mixing terms here, your question text is ambiguous. Like Chloe said, you cannot push a file from a server to a client and then have it execute. **It is the software on the client** machine that initiates or allows the download and starts the execution. So the first paragraph of your question in itself **is not possible** - you must install software on *that computer*. Even then, any software that would start execution of a download without user intervention is a big security risk - I certainly would not leave that running on *my* machines.

Answer (score 1):

Free Download Manager has a remote download feature "Create new downloads or view the list of active and completed downloads remotely, via the internet" see http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm